# node js - MSSQL node module automatically converts Date as DateTime

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm retrieving the SQL Date value from sql database using MSSQL node module through node js application but the resultant record set returns the date as Date time value.

2020-11-21 in database is displayed as 2020-11-21T00:00:00

Should we need to handle this explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

This is not "DateTime", that's how `toString` of a `Date` object looks like in Javascript:

[image]

If you want it to be printed in a certain format that shows only the "date" portion, you can use `toLocaleDateString()`:

```
const d = new Date()
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString()) // '11/18/2020'
```

or, if you want the result to be formatted like the example above: `yyyy-mm-dd` you can do:

```
d.toISOString().slice(0, 10); // '2020-11-18'
```